# Is it possible to define a method on the Proto enum?

Tags: java, enums, protocol-buffers, proto

Say I have a Proto buffer enum `operations.proto`

```
enum Operation {
  UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  PLUS = 1;
  MINUS = 2;
  TIMES = 3;
  DIVIDE = 4;
}
```

So in my Java code, I have to do something like

```
if (operation == Operation.PLUS) {
  return x+y;
} else if (operation == Operation.MINUS) {
  return x-y;
}
...
```

And I know I can do better with "Effective Java Item 34: Use enums instead of int constants" to have a method on the enum type like

```
public enum Operation {
  PLUS {public double apply(double x, double y){return x + y;}},
  MINUS {public double apply(double x, double y){return x - y;}},
  TIMES {public double apply(double x, double y){return x * y;}},
  DIVIDE{public double apply(double x, double y){return x / y;}};
  public abstract double apply(double x, double y);
}
```

However, my `Operation` is a proto enum instead of java enum. I can imagine I can map the proto enum to Java enum and define methods on the Java enum (not sure if this overcomplicates the issue). But is there any smart way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot add your own methods to enums generated for protobufs.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not a thing that the schema DSL allows.

This exists for services, but that is thinking of things like gRPC.